# How do I change the javascript loading order

Tags: 8, javascript

I am using mixitup.js for my custom module. But it gives error when firing because it needs to load the jQuery before loading the mixitup.js. But my jQuery files are in my site folder which are loading in the end of the page. Is there way to load my mixitup.js in the end of the page. mixitup.js should be in my custom module too.

Comment: What do you mean with "...in site folder..."? jQuery is part of Drupal's core, just add a dependency to `core/jquery` it in your module's `library.yml` file, you don't need any manual load ordering.

Comment: How are you adding the scripts? This will determine the solution.

Comment: @Jaypan in the library.yml

Comment: @Hudri Yes. I have already added jQuery to libraries.yml. But that too loads in the end of the page. Not on the top. I need to load all the javascripts at the top of the page.

Comment: Do you truly want all js in the header? or just the js used by your custom module?

Comment: See sonfd's reply below. That's the way to do it. If you set jquery as a dependeny, jQuery will load above it.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan, updated my answer to include that info.

Comment: I'm not clear - you've been given the information you need - is your problem solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a js library to the header, define your library in `my_module.libraries.yml` with the `header: true` property.

```
my_library:
  header: true
  etc ...
```

Any dependencies defined for your library will always be loaded before your library whether loading your js in the header or footer.

See Asset loading order section [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme).

Answer (score 4):

As mentionned above, one way to control the order is to declare in your library the dependencies of other libraries containing the js you want to be loaded before

```
agenda:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    component:
      css/agenda.css: {}
  js:
    js/agenda.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - fullcalendar_view/fullcalendar
```